# why is behaviour of simpl differ so much after a commutative operation and how to inspect simpl?

Tags: proof-techniques, coq

In Coq, while trying to prove a lemma `mult_n_Sm` for `mult_comm`, I have this equation in a proof:

```
S n * S m = S n * m + S n      (* simpl. *)
S (m + n * S m) = m + n * m + S n
```

Lets look at right hand side of the equation. `S n * m + S n` was simplified into `m + n*m + S n`.( by definition of nat, `S n = n + 1`, hence `(n+1)*m = m + n*m`).

but if you use `plus_comm` (the commutative theorem) on the right hand side then perform `simpl`, it was simplified like following:

```
(* rewrite <- plus_comm *)
S n * S m = S n + S n * m      (* simpl. *) 
S (m + n * S m) = S (n + (m + n * m))
```

How was `S n + S n * m` simplified into `S(n + (m + n * m))`? By definition of `plus`, `S n + S n * m = S ( n + S n * m )`, but what was used to change `S n * m` into `m + n * m` without invoking `mult_comm` and `mult_n_Sm` itself?

It feels like the simpl. tactic used something that I tried to prove, forming an undesirable cyclic proof. How to inspect what atomic tactics `simpl` had performed under the hood?